# Fatal Error on Admin Category Page - Error: Call to undefined method ProFi\CompanyAccount\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Dummy::setCategory()

Tags: magento2, php

I'm getting this error on admin category page. I'm not sure where to start to debug.

Error: Call to undefined method ProfFi\CompanyAccount\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Dummy::setCategory() in /app/code/ProFi/ShopbyProFi/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/ModifyDataProvider.php:52

Would you have any idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at `app/code/ProFi/ShopbyProFi/Plugin/Catalog/Model/Category/DataProvider/ModifyDataProvider.php` line 52.

Here you will see it call `setCategory` method from `ProfFi\CompanyAccount\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Dummy` class, but that method does not exist in `ProfFi\CompanyAccount\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Dummy` class.